# Excel VBA Sort with formulas - Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have checked all of the forums questions that relate to this topic.  I am unable to get my code to work.

Here is the code.  Please let me know what I need to correct.

```
Dim strDataRange As String
Dim strKeyRange As String

strDataRange = "B" & strStartRow & ":M" & strLastRow
strKeyRange = "B" & strStartRow & ":B" & strLastRow

Range(strDataRange).Sort Key1:=strKeyRange, Order1:=xlDescending,   Header:=xlNo
```

The `strDataRange` is `B5:M18`.

The `strKeyRange` is `B5:B18`.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
Range(strDataRange).Sort Key1:=Range(strKeyRange), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
```

since [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) method wants `Key1`parameter as *"...sort field, either as a range name (String) or Range object"*

Comment: I changed to be "Range(strDataRange).Sort Key1:=Range(strKeyRange), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo"      This is still giving me an error 1004:  "This operation requires the merged cells to be identically sized."  I don't have any merged cells in the sort range.

Comment: Do you have any merged cell in B5:M18?

Comment: No.  No merged cells at all in the sort range as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  Since the VBA codes was on a different worksheet than where I was sorting, I needed to add the workbook reference; which is "ws".

here is the corrected code

```
 ws.Range(strDataRange).Sort Key1:=ws.Range(strKeyRange), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
```

Thanks for all your help.